# How to deliver five notification for five different times everyday?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am working on an islamic PrayerTimes  app that gives five prayertimes a day.So my goal for now is to deliver five notifications to the user everyday at specific prayerTimes. then i created  five notifications for each prayers , assigned five firedate for each notification, and i can get the notification delivered .

However , my problem is every time i run the app or restart the app i am having a notification on notification center, at the console area i can see all the older notifications are delivered as well (I overrode application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method).

Frankly I am not a experienced developer , i really didn't get this , and I thought my code is very long. 
So can somebody help me and tell  how can i manage to do this ? :) (my english is not that good please be tolerant). if i missed some other sing to inform ,please tell.

Here is my code ;

Edit: I call this mehod from viewDidLoad.

I　got five times in an array blow:

```
 NSSArray *timeArray = @[time0,time1,time2,time3,time4];
```

I sceduled five UILocalNotification like this:

```
   if (localNotification0 != nil) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification0];
}
NSDate *date0 = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"date %@",date0);
localNotification0 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification0.fireDate = date0;
localNotification0.timeZone =[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSLog(@"firedate %@",localNotification0.timeZone);
localNotification0.alertBody = @"Se";
localNotification0.soundName = _adhanName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification0];


if (localNotification1 != nil) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification1];
}
NSDate *date1 = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:1];
localNotification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification1.fireDate = date1;
NSLog(@"firedate %@",localNotification1.fireDate);
localNotification1.timeZone =[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification1.alertBody = @"Se";
localNotification1.soundName = _adhanName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification1];
[localNotification1 release];

if (localNotification2 != nil) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification2];
}
NSDate *date2 = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:2];
localNotification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification2.fireDate = date2;
localNotification2.timeZone =[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSLog(@"firedate %@",localNotification2.fireDate);

localNotification2.alertBody = @"Se";
localNotification2.soundName = _adhanName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification2];
[localNotification2 release];


if (localNotification3 != nil) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification3];
}
NSDate *date3 = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:3];
localNotification3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification3.fireDate = date3;
localNotification3.timeZone =[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSLog(@"firedate %@",localNotification3.fireDate);

localNotification3.alertBody = @"Se";
localNotification3.soundName = _adhanName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification3];
[localNotification3 release];

if (localNotification4 != nil) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification4];
}
NSDate *date4 = [_timeArray objectAtIndex:4];
localNotification4 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification4.fireDate = date4;
localNotification4.timeZone =[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
NSLog(@"firedate %@",localNotification4.fireDate);

localNotification4.alertBody = @"Se";
localNotification4.soundName = _adhanName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification4];
[localNotification4 release];
```

Is there other more easy way to do this ? pleas help me out!

Comment: please clarify: you do not want to receive notifications while your app is not running?

Comment: no, I am getting extra notification every time i start the app , run for test . i just want five notification for a day ,

Comment: what does the extra notification say? it usually has a userinfo-property. Thats a NSDictonary. Log its content and ppost it, please.

Comment: i do not understand. You are receiving a UILocalNotification, yes? Please do this where appropriate: `NSLog("%@", notification.userInfo);` . replace "notification" with the name of your notification-object, if necessary. Post whatever it writes to the console.

Comment: to be more clear: "where appropiate" means "in your overridden `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`- method".

Comment: or, in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, try this: `NSLog(@"%@", [[options valueForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] userInfo]);` . again, post the output in the console. thanks

Comment: please mind the two edits in the comment above.

Comment: for which log-statement? also, it needs to read `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` above. Also, how exactly do you know of this "extra Notification"?

Comment: is there *ANY* text connected to this notification? a name, a class, anything at all? give me something to work with, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, it looks like you can shorten your code by using a loop, something like this:

```
for (NSDate *time in times) {
    if (localNotification3 != nil) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification3];
    }
    UILocalNotification *note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    note.fireDate = time;
    note.timeZone =[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    note.alertBody = @"Se";
    note.soundName = _adhanName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:note];
    [note release]; // no need to release note if you use ARC
}
```

That loop will run once for each entry in your `times` array, reducing the amount of code you need by a factor of 5, in this case, or `[times count]` in general.

> every time i run the app or restart the app i am having a notification on notification center

I'm not sure I fully understand what's wrong here, but if any/all the notifications are being presented too soon, it sounds like you should check the times for which they're scheduled. If the problem is that your app keeps scheduling new notifications every time it starts, resulting in too many notifications, then you have at least two options:

- use `-cancelAllLocalNotifications` before you schedule any new notifications
- record the times for which notifications have already been scheduled (NSUserDefaults is good for that kind of thing) and avoid scheduling new notifications for those times

Comment: thanks alot Caleb. you answer is very helpful. you are right my problem is that the app keeps scheduling new notifications every time it starts. everytime the scduleNotification method is called , there is a new notification delivered.

Comment: Could you provide me further knowledge about -cancelAllLocalNotifications or NSUserDefaults . i will be appreciated

Comment: @Ezimettekin If you still need more info, your best bet is to look up either of those methods in the Cocoa Touch documentation. `-cancelAllLocalNotifications` does what you'd expect based on the name; NSUserDefaults is straightforward mechanism for storing preferences and other small amounts of information.